# What is the difference between new Date() and Date() when used as variable?

Tags: javascript

For eg-

```
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var x = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
</script>
</body>
```

And,

```
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var x = Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
</script>
</body>
```

The result is same.But what it means when we use 'new'?

Comment: More information about JavaScript new keyworkd in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript.

Answer (score -2):

**Date()**

With this you call a function called `Date()`. It doesn't accept any arguments and returns a string representing the current date and time.

**new Date()**

With this you're creating a new instance of Date.

You can use only the following constructors:

```
new Date() // current date and time
new Date(milliseconds) //milliseconds since 1970/01/01
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

So, use 2010-08-17 12:09:36 as parameter to constructor is not allowed.

See w3schools.

Comment: @SankarRaj it does not care about any argument if you don't add new keywork before...

Comment: @SankarRaj "does not as comment above says.